# How to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, inverse

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
        4I_k+4\left(\frac{m-2}{m+2}\right)J_{k,k} &  -\frac{8}{m+2}J_{k,m-k}  \\\
       -\frac{8}{m+2}J_{m-k,k} &  4I_{m-k}-\frac{4}{m+2}J_{m-k,m-k}\\
        \end{array}\right]
$$

My calculated results do not match with the computer results. $I_m$ is an identity matrix and $J_{m,m}$ is a matrix of ones. Note that $2 \le k \le m-2 $.

Comment: Hello and welcome! It would be helpful if you could preovide more detail (what method have you used to come up with an answer?). Also, the two matrices in the top left block can't be added. Do you mean $I_{k}$ instead of $I_m$?

Comment: I just edit that. My bad. I tried block determinant and to try to get the inverse using Sherman-Morrison Formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Hans Engler, write $M = 4 I_m + B$, and let the nonzero eigenvalues of $B$ be $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Let
 $$\eqalign{t_1 &= \text{Trace}(B) = 4 k (m-2)/(m+2) - 4 (m-k)/(m+2)\cr
            t_2 &= \text{Trace}(B^2) = \dfrac{16}{(m+2)^2} \left(((m-2)^2 k+4 (m-k)) k + (4 k+m-k) (m-k)\right) \cr}$$
Then $t_1 =  d_1 + d_2$ 
and $t_2  = d_1^2 + d_2^2$.  Thus $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the roots of 
$ 2 x^2 - 2 t_1 x + t_1^2 - t_2 = 0$, i.e. 
$$d_1, d_2 = \dfrac{t_1}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{2 t_2 - t_1^2}}{2}$$

Comment: That works. Can you explain the math behind this? Or maybe some reference to read?

Answer (score 3):

This is a rank 2 perturbation of a multiple of the identity matrix. It may be written in the form $M = 4I_m + B$ where $B$ is the remainder term. This term in turn has the form $B =  d_1 aa^T + d_2 bb^T$ where $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal and have norm 1.

Then the eigenvalues are $4 + d_1, 4 + d_2$ (each with multiplicity 1) and 4 (multiplicity $m-2$).